# Weblogic gets error when manually deploy ear file

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

When I deploy my ear application manually into the WebLogic Server and I try to start the ear file, I come across with the following error that you can see below. Do you know the reason behind it ? I am using WebLogic 12.1.2. Maybe the version of Weblogic is the major problem behind ?

Thank you for your helps

```
     weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "WebAppModule(awp-claim-comm-ear:/AWPClaimCommWeb)", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: beehive-controls-1.0.1-10.0-war, Specification-Version: 1, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: jstl, Specification-Version: 1.1, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: struts-1.2, Specification-Version: 1.2, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: weblogic-controls-10.0-war, Specification-Version: 10, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: wls-commonslogging-bridge-war, Specification-Version: 1, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: beehive-netui-1.0.1-10.0, Specification-Version: 1, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: beehive-netui-resources-1.0.1-10.0, Specification-Version: 1, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: AWPCommonWebLib, Specification-Version: 1, Implementation-Version: 1.0.0, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: AWPEjbWebLib, Specification-Version: 1, Implementation-Version: 1.0.0, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: AWPSsoWebLib, Specification-Version: 1, exact-match: true]
```

Comment: One or more shared libraries used by your application are miising in the domain. Read your weblogic.xml file and check if all referenced shared libs are deployed in your domain.

Comment: yea you are right Emmanuel. They are not in my domain. I thought the problem will be fixed if I install Weblogic with maybe a new version, right ?

Comment: Installing a new WebLogic Server version will not resolve your issue. You must first deploy shared libs required by your application.

Comment: what is the exact location of the shared libs Emmanuel at the weblogic ?

Comment: Shared libs are weblogic j2ee artifacts (war, jar, ear) deployed in the same way as applications. There is no specific location.